# Using PHP to check if an Element(ID) has a specific class assigned

Tags: php, css, class, drupal, element

I want in my template.php (drupal theme) something like this:

```
$search_button ='search-button.png';
if($('#page-wrapper').hasClass('blue-colour')) {
    $search_button ='search-button-blue.png';
}
else if ($('#page-wrapper').hasClass('green-colour')) {
    $search_button ='search-button-green.png';
}
$form['actions']['submit'] = array('#type' => 'image_button', '#src' => base_path() . path_to_theme() . '/images/'.$search_button);
```

Which doesn't work because it is jQuery. The problem is the syntax on this bit:

> if($('#page-wrapper').hasClass('blue-colour'))

How can I do the same thing without using javascript or jQuery and only php and/or some Drupal function?

I want to replace the icon for a search box based on a class set on a HTML element:

```
<div id="page-wrapper" class="blue-colour">
```

In this case it would check that the class is 'blue-colour' and would set the correct blue icon on the variable ($search_button).

Comment: I am assuming the theme can be blue or green. How are you telling it to choose which to use?

Comment: Wow, how many times does this have to be explained here? PHP only runs on the server and doesn't have any chance of knowing what the state of the DOM tree is. The **ONLY** way to do this in the browser is with javascript.

Comment: h00ligan, I am new to this and I have searched a lot for an answer and didn't find one. Since the source HTML is also on the server and the class is not dinamically assigned I thought there would be a way to do this without JS.

Comment: @JoaoJesus If the class isn't dynamically assigned then surely the check isn't necessary, you already know the class as it is set. How is the class being set? Hard coded in the HTML?

Comment: You are right. I will try using variables across templates. Not sure why I didn't think about this earlier. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't answer your question directly, but you can solve this very nicely using just css:

1. Don't use an image for your button, but a text and do something like `text-indent: -9999em;`
2. Set the background image of the button to the image you want like (simple example):

> 

```
.blue-colour .button {
   background: url(search-button-blue.png);
}
.green-colour .button {
   background: url(search-button-green.png);
}
```

Comment: This is actually a good and simple workaround. I will give it a try if using variables across templates is too much effort. Thanks.

Comment: Used this approach. Much simpler to apply and the images are now set on the css which is the way to go. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

javascript and jQuery are client-side, meaning the page is already loaded and javascript operates on the loaded DOM directly on the client's computer.

PHP is server-side, meaning the page is being written by PHP on the server and then the hypertext will be transferred to the client's computer.

Changing the image based on the class would require client-side code unless you already knew the class.

For example,

```
$class = 'blue-colour';
switch ($class) {
    case 'blue-colour':
        echo '<img src="blue-colour.jpg" alt="blue-colour" />'
        break;
    default:
        echo '<img src="default.jpg" alt="default" />';
}
```

How you determine the class is up to your code, but it has to be done during the parsing on the page.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use dom parser, though its going to be tricky.

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm